# Elinks or Lynx?

Tags: browser, lynx, text-based, elinks

Please, state your reasons for your terminal browser. Why are you using Lynx or Elinks? How do they help you in programming?

Comment: One of the main reasons that i use lynx is to see how my web page(s) is viewed by a search engine. Also, Elinks over lynx for HTTPS support.

Comment: @ShripadK: it would be helpful to mention how lynx is better than Elinks for seeing how your pages are viewed by search engines.  Also, you might want to make that an answer instead of just a comment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're asking which I prefer for a more complete browsing experience, I prefer Elinks. It has tabbed browsing, download/password managing, and tabbed navigation (handy when in a terminal). It also (partially) supports CSS 2.1, (fully) supports frames. It also (partially) supports JavaScript. Not as important, but Elinks supports more protocols than Lynx (I specifically use the Bittorrent protocol).

If you're asking which is more suitable for testing text-only browsers, Lynx is probably more popular, but Elinks is still a great choice here as well.

For comparision look [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_browsers).

Comment: Tabbed browsing? Does Links2 have it too?

Comment: I don't use links2, but try with -g (graphical mode).

Comment: I know this answer was written 5 years ago, and ELinks has it's latest update 5 years ago as well. For the newer users, ELinks is dead. It's not being updated anymore. Though it doesn't stop you from using it but I'd prefer either Links or Lynx as an alternative.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from [*A comparison of text-based browsers.*](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/a-comparison-of-text-based-browsers/) This text contains reviews and screen shots of six text-based browsers.

> Lynx does a lot of the things elinks does, and does a fairly quick and clean job doing it.
>
> I found only one options page and it is very easy to navigate. In fact, one of the things I liked best about lynx was it’s flat approach to configuration. Everything is right there, and easy to control.
>
> That being said, lynx probably has the most configuration options at the command line of all the six listed here. Looking over the --help list, it seems like just about anything can be turned on or off … even turning things on or off.

### Screen-shot of lynx

[image: lynx]

### Screen-shot of elinks

[image: elinks]

Comment: How does these compare from a security perspective?

Answer (score 6):

This is a complement of [Nick Presta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604699/938111).

There are [ten text-based web browsers listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser). The three most active are:

1. [**`elinks`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks) is the active version of [**`links`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)). Its [Git repo](http://repo.or.cz/w/elinks.git) is alive ([six 0.12 beta versions since July 2008](http://www.elinks.cz/news/2008.html)) but last stable release is old ([0.11.7 in August 2009](http://www.elinks.cz/news.html)).
2. [**`lynx`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29) is a bit more active than `elinks` and last stable release is almost as old ([2.8.7rel.2 in June 2010](http://lynx.isc.org/current/index.html#release_top)). The [RCS/PRCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System) repository is not public but you can check activity of the [lynx-dev mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lynx-dev/).
3. [**`w3m`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m) can display pictures on xterm and can handle table, cookies, authentication, and almost everything except JavaScript. [Last stable release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/w3m/files/w3m/) is not so old (0.5.3 in January 2011) but [CVS repo](http://w3m.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/w3m/w3m/?sortby=date) is sleeping.

See also [findthebest.com](http://web-browsers.findthebest.com/compare/8-18-25-26/w3m-vs-ELinks-vs-Lynx-vs-Links) that compares software based on their technical data.

While testing these browsers through a proxy (using `http_proxy=http://user:pwd@host:port/`) I have been pleased to see that **`lynx`** requested for `user` and `password` so you can avoid putting them on `http_proxy`.

Comment: How does these compare from a security perspective?

Comment: Hi @Motivated Good question... I do not know. Have you spend some time to check the security about these tools? Have fun

Answer (score 2):

I use them as a rough visual metaphor for what it must be like to use a screen-reader.  When I am addressing accessibility concerns I use Lynx to check the page when I don't have access to a screen-reader.

Why do I use Lynx?  Because I wasn't aware of any alternatives!

Comment: How secure is Lynx as my understanding is that it isn't actively developed?

Answer (score 1):

CLI web browsers are still sometimes noticeably faster than GUI browsers.

More importantly, they're also more distraction-free (no images, JavaScript, Flash, etc.), in much the same vein as apps like [WriteRoom](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/writeroom).

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons for using lynx:

1. It's a great way to see a lower-level of the HTTP transaction going on with the server (though, of course, you can do this with curl and such tools, but it's a pain to post forms in those tools :-) ).
2. I can test whether or not my HTML really holds up to a lesser browsing experience where users have images turned off... I can verify that the ALT tags make sense, etc.

Comment: If you have lynx 2.2 or higher, put the proxy configuration in your lynx.cfg file: http://lynx.isc.org/release/lynx2-8-7/lynx_help/body.html#HTTP_PROXY

Comment: What about security considerations? Is Lynx more secure? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Lynx, because sometimes I want to look something up without getting sucked into a GUI.  But it's getting increasingly less frequent over the years, as the slowly but steadily increasing overhead of firing up X has failed to keep up with Moore's Death March of performance.

At this point I pretty much keep a GUI shell up and don't even worry about it.

-- MarkusQ

Comment: any idea how to setup a proxy in Lynx? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494849/how-to-set-a-pro-xy-server-for-connecting-to-the-internet-in-lynx

Comment: elinks is also a terminal browser, so comparing lynx with a GUI browser misses the point of the question.